# How to make Vim autocomplete with file system?

Tags: autocompletion

Let's say I have my directory/file tree as follows:

```
/
|_home
  |_myPC
    |_script.sh
    |_test.sh
|_etc
  |_log.txt
```

I'm working on `script.sh` and Vim has nothing like `firejail` to stop it from accessing stuff.

So far, I'm able to, with [ctrlp](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/ctrlp-vim-everything-has-changed), auto-complete with stuff already in `script.sh`. However, when I type `cat ~/t` and use `<C-p>` (with ctrlp), I want it to auto-complete to `cat ~/test.sh` or offer that. However, ctrlp alone only seems to access stuff already in `script.sh`.

How can I make Vim auto-complete with the system file tree? Is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<C-x><C-f>` to enter filename completion.

Vim will understand the partial path already typed and offer you suggestions from paths in the filesystem. You can use the usual `<C-p>` and `<C-n>` to navigate the completion menu, also `<C-f>` works the same as `<C-n>` in this specific menu.

If you pick a directory name, you can use an additional `<C-x><C-f>` to start completing the next path component, and so on.

You can use `<C-y>` to accept the current entry and leave completion, or `<C-e>` to cancel it.

You don't actually need any plug-ins, this is all a built-in feature of Vim.

See [`:help compl-filename`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-filename) for filename completion in specific, though you might want to have a look at the whole [`:help ins-completion`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#ins-completion) for a more complete overview of insert mode completion in Vim.